# React native problemas al subir imagen con datos en php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

no se están subiendo los datos este es mi React Native:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import {View,Text,StyleSheet,TextInput,TouchableOpacity,Image} from 'react-native';

import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'; import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

const options={
    title:'select a photo',
    takePhotoButtonTitle:'Take a Photo',
    chooseFrmoLibraryButtonTitle:'Choose from Gallery',
    quality:1 };


class InputUsers extends Component{

//constructor have a state that conatains the properties that will recieve the values from Text Inputes
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
        this.state = {
            TextInputName:'',
            TextInputEmail:'',
            TextInputPhoneNumber:'',
            iamgeSource: null,
            data: [
                    {
                        value: 'Computadoras encendidas',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'Puerta Abierta',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'llaves perdidas',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'Retraso de personal',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'alarmas desactivadas',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'personal no reconocido',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'Agresion',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'Aulas desordenadas',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'No hay empleados',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'No llego compa;ero',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'Fugas de gas',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'Puerta esta cerrada',
                    },
                ],
        }
    }

    selectPhoto(){
        ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);

            if (response.didCancel) {
              console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            }
            else if (response.error) {
              console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            }
            else {
              let source = { uri: response.uri };
              this.setState({
                iamgeSource: source
              });
            }
          });
    }

//arrow function that will fire when press on save button to save data in database via API InsertUser = ()=>{ //constant varaibles that equal propertes in state const {TextInputName} = this.state; const {TextInputEmail} = this.state; const {TextInputPhoneNumber} = this.state; const {iamgeSource} = this.state;

const formData = new FormData(); //Add your input data formData.append('name', TextInputName); formData.append('email', TextInputEmail); formData.append('phone_number', TextInputPhoneNumber);

//Add your photo //this, retrive the file extension of your photo const uriPart = iamgeSource.uri.split('.'); const fileExtension = uriPart[uriPart.length - 1];

formData.append('iamgeSource', {
    uri: iamgeSource.uri,
    name: 'iamgeSource',
    type: 'image/jpeg', });

//API that use fetch to input data to database via backend php script fetch('http://192.168.0.16/conex/insert.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      body: formData   })   .then((response) => response.json())   .then((responseJson) => {    // return responseJson
     alert(responseJson);
     this.props.navigation.navigate('home');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

//alert('Pressed!!'); }


    render(){
        return(
            <View style ={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                // value = {this.TextInputName}
                 placeholder = 'Descripcion del incidente'
                 onChangeText = {TextInputValue=>this.setState({TextInputName:TextInputValue}) }
                 underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                 style = {styles.TextInputStyle}
                />

                <View style={styles.textInput2}>
                  <Dropdown
                    label="Seleccion incidente"
                    data={this.state.data}
                    onChangeText= {TextInputValue=>this.setState({TextInputEmail:TextInputValue}) }
                  />
                </View>



                <Image style={styles.image}
                    source={this.state.iamgeSource != null ? this.state.iamgeSource : require('./image/blogSix.png')}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.TouchableOpacityStyle} onPress={this.selectPhoto.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style = {styles.TextStyle}>Seleccione la foto</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = {.4} style = {styles.TouchableOpacityStyle} onPress={this.InsertUser}>
                    <Text style = {styles.TextStyle}>Enviar incidente</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>



            </View>
        )
    } }

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    container : {
        alignItems:'center',
        flex:1,
        marginTop:5,
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    },

    TextInputStyle :{
        textAlign:'center',
        marginBottom:7,
        width:'90%',
        height:40,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderRadius:5,
        borderColor:'#FF5722'
    },

    TextInputStyle2 :{
        textAlign:'center',
        marginBottom:7,
        marginTop:20,
        width:'90%',
        height:40,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderRadius:5,
        borderColor:'#FF5722'
    },

    TextStyle : {
        color:'#fff',
        textAlign:'center'
    },

    TouchableOpacityStyle:{
        paddingTop:10,
        paddingBottom:10,
        marginTop:20,
        borderRadius:5,
        marginBottom:7,
        width:'90%',
        backgroundColor:'#00BCD4'
    },

    button:{
        width:250,
        height:50,
        backgroundColor:"#330066"
    },

    text:{
        color:'white',
        fontSize:30,
        textAlign:'center'
    },

    textInput2: {
      textAlign:'center',
      marginBottom:7,
      marginTop:20,
      width:'90%',
      height:40,
      borderWidth:1,
      borderRadius:5,
      borderColor:'#FF5722',
      paddingBottom:25,

    },

    image:{
        width:200,
        height:200,
        marginTop:30
    }



});

export default InputUsers;
```

Este es mi archivo php

```
<?php include 'config2.php';

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);

    $name = $obj['name'];
    $email = $obj['email'];
    $phone_number = $obj['phone_number'];
    $iamgeSource = $obj['iamgeSource'];

    if(mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(name,lastname, city, photo)VALUES('$name','$email','$phone_number','$iamgeSource')")){
        echo json_encode('Incidente incertado correctamente');
    }else{
        echo json_encode('Fallo a el enviar el incidente');
    }

    mysqli_close($db);
```

esta es la data base

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué error te marca?

Comment: ninguno, todo se sube bien, pero no me guarda los datos, sin la imagen se guardaba todo bien, con la imagen , dice que todo se subio bien, pero no guarda.

Comment: sera porque estas enviando la ruta y no un blob o base 64 por ejemplo